# How to get Python dictionary via Flask request files attribute

Tags: python, flask, request, python-requests

With `server.py` running:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET','POST'])
def route():   
    print('got files: %s' % request.files)
    return Response()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', 5000)
```

send a request using `client.py`:

```
import json, requests  

dictionary_1 = {"file": {"url": "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py"}}  

files = [('dictionary_1', ('get-pip.py', json.dumps(dictionary_1), 'application/json'))]

response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/test', files=files)
```

Server logs that it received a request:

```
got files: ImmutableMultiDict([('dictionary_1', <FileStorage: u'get-pip.py' ('application/json')>)])
```

Apparently, the `dictionary_1` was received as `FileStorage` object.
How to turn the received `FileStorage` into the Python dictionary?

## edited later

The possible duplicate post does not clarify how to send and unpack the Python dictionary object sent via `requests(files=list())`

Comment: The post you've mentioned does not clarify how to send and unpack the dictionary object using Flask.request.files attribute.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're posting files instead of data. This should work:

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET','POST'])
def route():   
    print('got data: {}'.format(flask.request.json))
    return Response()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', 5000)
```

and then send data to your app by

```
import requests  

dictionary_1 = {"file": {"url": "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py"}}  

response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/test', json=dictionary_1)
```

In your example there's no need to post the file unless I'm misunderstanding something

Comment: I am intentionally using the `requests.post(url, files=list())` and not `requests.post(url, json=str())` since I would like to be able to send both the files and dictionary with the same request.

Comment: @alphanumeric Your request doesn't include any files. The variable `multiple_files` in the client contains only dicts, lists, and strings.

Comment: Since I would like to keep the question as simple as possible the `multiple_files` list contains the dictionary object only and not the files.

Answer (score 1):

Solution # 1:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response
import StringIO, json 

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET','POST'])
def route():  
    print('got files: %s' % request.files)
    for key, file_storage in request.files.items():
        string_io = StringIO.StringIO()
        file_storage.save(string_io)
        data = json.loads(string_io.getvalue())
        print('data: %s type: %s' % (data, type(data)) ) 

    return Response()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', 5000)
```

Solution # 2:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response
import tempfile, json, os, time   

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET','POST'])
def route():   
    print('got files: %s' % request.files)

    for key, _file in request.files.items():
        tmp_filepath = os.path.join(tempfile.mktemp(), str(time.time()))
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(tmp_filepath)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(tmp_filepath))

        _file.save(tmp_filepath)

        with open(tmp_filepath) as f:
            json_data = json.loads(f.read())

        print type(json_data), json_data 

    return Response(json_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', 5000)
```